# Laravel Broadcast Doesn't Send Message

Tags: laravel, eloquent, broadcast, laravel-echo

I'm having trouble with sending new messages to users. I really tried a lot of things but they didn't solve the problem. I think client successfully connected to the websocket but there is no submitted message from the socket.

Here are my codes:

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('Conversations.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
}, ['guards' => ['web', 'auth']]);
```

MessageObserver.php

```
class MessageObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the ConversationMessage "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ConversationMessage  $conversationMessage
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(ConversationMessage $message)
    {

        $conversation = $message->conversation;

        $user = $conversation->other_user;

        $notify = [
            "to" => $user->id,
            "from" => [
                "id" => Auth::user()->id,
                "username" => Auth::user()->username,
                "name" => Auth::user()->name,
                "avatar" => Auth::user()->avatar,
            ],
            'message' => $message->message,
            'attachment' => $message->attachment,
            'attachment_mime' => $message->attachment_mime,
            "created_at" => $message->created_at,
        ];

        broadcast(new \App\Events\NewMessage($user->id, $notify));

    }

}
```

App\Events\NewMessage

```
class NewMessage
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $to;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($to, Array $message)
    {

        $this->message = $message;
        $this->to = $to;

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {

        return [new PrivateChannel('Conversations.'.$this->to)];

    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'messages';
    }
}
```

Lastly.. Conversation.js

```
window.laravelEcho.private(`Conversations.${usePage().props.value.auth.user.id}`)  
.listen(`messages`, (messages) => {

    console.log(messages)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. The event class should implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast`.

To solve my problem, i added this:

```
class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
```